# Multiply two columns and result in another column

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am looking to do some calculation in my table. The table content comes from ajax. But with the below, the calculation completes for one row only (First Row). When i tried to add .each with the function nothing happens.

**AJAX Code**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: '@Url.Action("function", "Controller")',
        data: '{selectedValues: "' + selectedValues + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var row = "";
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                row += "<tr class='odd'><td><input type='checkbox'></td><td class='product-title'>" + item.Name + "</td><td>" + item.MaxIssueLimit + "</td><td class='num-pallets'><input type='text' class='num-pallets-input' id='sparkle-num-pallets'  max=" + item.MaxIssueLimit + " oninput='calculate()'></input></td><td class='times'>X</td><td class='price-per-pallet'><input type='text' class='num-pallets-input' id='cost' oninput='calculate()' value=" + item.UnitPrice + " disabled='disabled'></td><td class='equals'>=</td><td class='row-total'><input type='text' class='row-total-input' id='sparkle-row-total' disabled='disabled'></input></td></tr>";                   
            });
            $("#contacts").html(row);

        },
    });
```

**Javascript**

```
function calculate() {              
        var my1 = document.getElementById('sparkle-num-pallets').value;
        var my2 = document.getElementById('cost').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('sparkle-row-total');
        var myResult = my1 * my2;
        result.value = myResult;     
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [parseInt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) before multiplying

> The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer.

`document.getElementById('sparkle-num-pallets').value;` returns a string.

you cannot multiply two strings you have parse them to integers.

```
function calculate() {              
        var my1 = document.getElementById('sparkle-num-pallets').value;
        var my2 = document.getElementById('cost').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('sparkle-row-total');
        var myResult = parseInt(my1) * parseInt(my2); // Parse the strings
        result.value = myResult;     
}
```

```js
function calculate() {
  var my1 = document.getElementById('sparkle-num-pallets').value;
  var my2 = document.getElementById('cost').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('sparkle-row-total');
  var myResult = parseInt(my1) * parseInt(my2); // Parse the strings
  result.value = myResult;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="sparkle-num-pallets" ></td>
      <td><input id="cost" ></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
<br/>
RESULT:
<input id="sparkle-row-total">
```

Comment: But how can i make it to work for all the rows in a table @Nadir Laskar

Comment: Same as shown. you need to parse the string to int or float depending upon what you want before doing any calculation.